# PHP Soap Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: php, web-service, soap, wsdl

Estou tentando efetuar o login em uma URL e aparece o seguinte erro:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Segue o código:

```
<?php
$clientSoap = new SoapClient( "http://www1.snd.com.br/Plugins/Atma.Plugin.Misc.ServiceAPI/Controllers/ServiceAPIEndpoint.svc?singleWsdl" );
$params = array('Login' => array(
                    'Usuario'   => 'usuario',
                    'Senha'     => 'senha'));


$result = $clientSoap->__soapCall('Login', $params);

print_r($result);      

?>
```

Já mudei e testei de várias formas e sempre dá o mesmo erro.

Comment: Posso estar errado, mas aparentemente o nome da função a ser chamada para login é 'LoginRequest' e não 'Login'. Tente e veja se isso funciona.

Você também pode fazer a chamada da função com $clientSoap->LoginRequest($params)

Comment: @ViniciusGabriel fiz as mudanças também não funciona